# JIRA API POST jql search

Tags: json, jira, jira-rest-api

I need to get a bulk of issues that `in` the array of keys.

A `GET` URL-request like `'...&issues in (key-1,key-2)...'` is not an option for me because of length of the array may be more than 200 so it will be a 2000+ chars URL request and it is not good as I red [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/5454565).

Here is [Jira's API example](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.12.0/?_ga=2.255447808.905880889.1538644347-1120207670.1497887447#api/2/search-searchUsingSearchRequest) but there is no comments about the `jql` property value format.

How should I fill the `JSON-POST-model`'s `jql` property for get issues by keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the `jql` as part of the request body. Here's a sample request body you can use for the `/search` endpoint using POST:

```
{
    "jql": "status in (Done, \"in progress\") OR issue in (TEST-1, TEST-2) ORDER BY created"
}
```